# Urbanairship delegate not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

I'm using UrbanAirship for handling push notification in my iOS App. I want to implement the UAPushNotificationDelegate . Here is my code in appdelegate.

```
//Appdelegate.m
UAConfig *config = [UAConfig defaultConfig];
[UAirship takeOff:config];

[[UAirship push] updateRegistration];
[UAirship push].userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
                                         UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
                                         UIUserNotificationTypeSound);

[UAirship push].autobadgeEnabled = YES;
[UAirship push].userPushNotificationsEnabled = YES;
PushHandler *pushHandlerDelegate = [[PushHandler alloc] init];
[UAirship push].pushNotificationDelegate = pushHandlerDelegate;
```

Here is my PushHandler.h file

```
// PushHandler.h
@interface PushHandler : NSObject<UAPushNotificationDelegate>

@end
```

Then I implemented UrbanAirship methods in my implementation file

```
- (void)receivedForegroundNotification:(NSDictionary *)notification fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
// Call the completion handler
   completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
}
- (void)launchedFromNotification:(NSDictionary *)notification    fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{
// Call the completion handler
   completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
}

- (void)launchedFromNotification:(NSDictionary *)notification actionIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler {
// Call the completion handler
   completionHandler()
}

- (void)receivedBackgroundNotification:(NSDictionary *)notification actionIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler {
// Call the completion handler
   completionHandler()
}

- (void)receivedBackgroundNotification:(NSDictionary *)notification fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
// Call the completion handler
   completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
}
```

But non of the functions are calling when I receive a push . Where am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Hi. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

UAPush only stores a weak reference to the delegate. You need to store a strong reference somewhere in your code.

Example:

```
@interface AppDelegate ()
@property(nonatomic, strong) PushHandler *pushHandlerDelegate;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    ...

    self.pushHandlerDelegate = [[PushHandler alloc] init];
    [UAirship push].pushNotificationDelegate = self.pushHandlerDelegate;
}
```

Comment: Hi .. Thanks for your answer, but still I can access only foreground notification.  When the app is in background, I can not get the push , Push is receiving, but it is not firing the "receivedBackgroundNotification: "  method.

Comment: APNS only wakes the app up if you send a content-available push and if background remote notifications are enabled. Also make sure background refresh is enabled and you did not kill the app through the task switcher.